# ViewPager animation drag

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am trying to learn more about Android UIs and I am playing around with several different UI designs. Right now I am working with a ViewPager using Fragments and trying to emulate the homescreen, but it is not working on all of my devices. On my 7" tablet it appears fine (See image below), but on the 10" tablet, the transition between pages seems to drag. Not only is it slow, but the image permanently skews across the screen (See image below). Both tablets are running Android 4.0.3. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is and how to fix it?

Images:

The 7" tablet working fine:

[image]

The 10" tablet after trying to swipe one page to the left:

[image]

Code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.layouttest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.layouttest.MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getAdapter().getCount()/2);
    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
        List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
        fragList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
        fragList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 3"));
        fragList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 4"));
        fragList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 5"));
        return fragList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyPageAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.layouttest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    }

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> list){
        super(fm);
        fragments = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void addItem(Fragment f){
        fragments.add(f);
    }

    public void removeItem(Fragment f){
        fragments.remove(f);
    }

    public void removeItem(int i){
        fragments.remove(i);
    }

}
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
package com.example.layouttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass. Activities that
 * contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface to handle
 * interaction events. Use the {@link MyFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 * 
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String text;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment using
     * the provided parameters.
     * 
     * @param param1
     *            Parameter 1.
     * @param param2
     *            Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MyFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MyFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            text = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        TextView message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        message.setText(text);
        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated to
     * the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

**fragment_my.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And what kind of an answer are you exactly expecting without posting any code?

Comment: Here is the site I used as a guide: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

All of the code is the same.

Comment: There. All the code provided for your viewing pleasure.